# IntelliJ could not open cp_init remapped class cache

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

Error messages:

```
Could not open cp_init remapped class cache for 84lx9p6n2zpeje0ln02a5z2g6 (C:\Program Files\Gradle\gradle-6.5.1\caches\6.1.1\scripts-remapped\wrapper_init2_8c5njlhvjxnei9381cev9pual\84lx9p6n2zpeje0ln02a5z2g6\cp_init3607aee355f62839c5e6f549478ccc87).
> Could not open cp_init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:\Users\ASUSX4~1\AppData\Local\Temp\wrapper_init2.gradle' (C:\Program Files\Gradle\gradle-6.5.1\caches\6.1.1\scripts\84lx9p6n2zpeje0ln02a5z2g6\cp_init\cp_init3607aee355f62839c5e6f549478ccc87).
   > Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.Verifier
```

I am using `intellij 2020 1.3`, `jdk 14`, `gradle 6.5.1`

Any solutions to fix this?

Comment: Seems 6.1.1 version is cached ("gradle-6.5.1\caches\6.1.1") which is incompatible. Please ensure that 6.1.1 version is not used and clean caches.

Comment: how to do that? I have that same error and it's driving me crazy! btw I'm using mac OS not Windows so it seems a cross platform bug

Comment: Please try 2020.2 IDE version.